# AWS script a downgrade of an instance to get around Insufficient capacity error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

my wheelhouse is def more IT than dev, but I was hoping to see if someone had some pointers for this since my research hasn't turned up much.

My workplace has some workstations in AWS EC2 and we've been running into some issues where we get an insufficient capacity error ([Amazon's Description of the error](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-insufficient-capacity-errors/))

Their general solution to the problem is "move your instance to another availability zone" which isn't a good solution in my case because it slows down network traffic between instances to a point where its almost unworkable.

Their other general solution is to downgrade the instance type- which is the solution we've been acting on. I'd love a way to script that downgrade to a place where if the instance fails to power with that error 3 times, it automatically downgrades.

I gotta be honest, I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to AWS-specific scripting so I'd appreciate even the most basic of pointers that anyone has :) appreciate you all

Comment: Have you tried `capacity reservation` in aws where you can reserve capacity. The only downsize is, if you do not use the full capacity, you are gonna pay for the reservation else no extra costs. Also check `On-Demand Instance limits`. Else, I would suggest to use small instance via autoscaling groups. There is no ready made method which can do what you are thinking.

Comment: It's def the most obvious answer to the problem, but the issue is that the owners of this company don't want to pay for it, hah. Appreciate the input anyway :)

Comment: So, if the only method is to downgrade, you can look at `Amazon EventBridge`. You can detec the failure from the event, then you need to think of a method for the 3 times you are thinking. You will need a lambda which can then turn off the node, change it's instance type and turn it on again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.